# Python Path import problems

Tags: python

I added a folder to my PYTHONPATH where I can put all of my Django Apps. I print sys.path, and everything looks good, the folder I want is there. However, when I go to import a module, it tells me that there's no module by that name. All the site-packages modules work fine. In all of my Django apps, there's an "_____init_____.py" like there's supposed to be. I heard that if those are created on windows there can be problems, but I couldn't dig up much more than that.

Comment: Care to include the error message console printout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it. Sorry Santa for not including the console print out. Windows was dumb and added an extra .py to the file when I created it. So everything was actually "pythonfile.py.py". Awesome.